# C++ Vector iterate over abstract class

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, sfml

Background info:
Me and a couple of friends are building this platform game in C++ with the help och sfml and box2d for a school assignment.
One of the requirements is that we follow the "MVC pattern".

We have created classes like Bullet and Character for the model. And BulletView and CharacterView (both inherits sf::Drawable which is an abstract class) for the view.

Instead of duplicating code for drawing and have two methods drawBullets and drawCharacter like this

```
void WorldView::drawBullets()
{
    std::vector<BulletView*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = bullets.begin() ; it < bullets.end(); it++ )
        window->draw(**it);
}

void WorldView::drawCharacters()
{
    std::vector<CharacterView*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = characters.begin() ; it < characters.end(); it++ )
        window->draw(*it);
}
```

I would like a more generic method using polymorhism which would look something like this:

```
void WorldView::drawVector(const std::vector<sf::Drawable*>& vector)
{
    std::vector<sf::Drawable*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = vector.begin() ; it < vector.end(); it++ )
        window->draw(**it);
}
```

The bulletView vector is declared like this:

```
std::vector<BulletView*> bullets;
```

Can't get this to work though. And I'm kind of new to C++ so please have mercy! I've tried searching but have not found very specific answers.

Errors I get while compiling.

> Error  8   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand >operand of type 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable >conversion) c:\users\niklas\multiplaya\sfml test\sfml test\view\worldview.cpp   409 >1  SFML_Test
>
> Error  7   error C2664: 'mp::WorldView::drawVector' : cannot convert parameter 1 from >'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'    c:\users\niklas\multiplaya\sfml >test\sfml test\view\worldview.cpp  402 1   SFML_Test

Comment: `std::vector bullets;` isn't a valid declaration: what is the template type of the vector?

Comment: @Autopulated it was a formatting issue, which I fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the polimorphism doesn't work at the level of the vectors, but at the levevel of the pointers they contain. So `std::vector<Derived*>` can never be passed as an `std::vector<Base*>`, since they are completely different types. However, you can fill an `std::vector<Base*>` with pointers to `Derived*`.

So, you should declare your bullet vector as

```
std::vector<Drawable*> bullets;
```

and fill it with `BulletView*`, for example:

```
bullets.push_back( new BulletView( some args) );

drawVector(bullets);
```

**Note**: In the code above I am sidestepping the issue of dynamically allocated object ownership. Obviously some mechanism must be in place for deleting the `BulletViews` at the right moment.

Comment: Hmm okey. I will probably just end up subclassing the sf::Drawable class with something like a "GameObjectView" class then. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using polymorphic vectors, use template function:

```
template <typename T>
void WorldView::drawVector(const std::vector<T*>& vector)
{
    typename std::vector<T*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = vector.begin() ; it < vector.end(); it++ )
        window->draw(**it);
}
```

By the way - vectors of raw pointers look suspicious to me. Who owns them (who creates them and who is responsible to delete them)? Consider using vectors of values or `boost::ptr_vector`

Answer (score 2):

There errors you're getting are produced from the assignment `it = vector.begin();` in your `for` loop. The problem is you're trying to assign the `iterator`(`it`) to `const iterator`(`vector.begin()`). You can't iterate over a data structure with a `const` iterator, because its value changes on each iteration. Also when traversing a data structure using iterators you should use the `operator !=` instead of `operator <`.

If you remove the `const` from `const std::vector& vector` things should work just fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! The problem seems to be what @juanchopanza said before though.

Answer (score 1):

You are imitating the [Composite Design-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

However your error is: you should write **replacing < by !=** because it is an **iterator** not an **int**

```
void WorldView::drawBullets()
{
    std::vector<BulletView*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = bullets.begin() ; it != bullets.end(); it++ )
        window->draw(**it);
}

void WorldView::drawCharacters()
{
    std::vector<CharacterView*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = characters.begin() ; it != characters.end(); it++ )
        window->draw(*it);
}
I would like a more generic method using polymorhism which would look something like this:

void WorldView::drawVector(const std::vector<sf::Drawable*>& vector)
{
    std::vector<sf::Drawable*>::iterator it;
    for ( it = vector.begin() ; it != vector.end(); it++ )
        window->draw(**it);
}
```

Comment: vector have random access iterators, which can be compared with `operator<`